# parsleyjs with multi steps form

Tags: parsley.js

I'mn creating a multi step form wizard (using Twitter Bootstrap Wizard) and looking at the Parsley multi step example I'm not sure how I would implement it if I have more then two steps my current form has at least 4 steps.

This is what I don't understand

```
<span class="next btn btn-info pull-right" data-current-block="1" data-next-block="2">Next ></span>
```

My next button is constant

Here is the parsley example

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate>
  <div class="first block1 show">
    <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" data-parsley-group="block1" required/>

    <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" data-parsley-group="block1" required />
    <span class="next btn btn-info pull-right" data-current-block="1" data-next-block="2">Next ></span>
  </div>

  <div class="second block2 hidden">
    <label for="fullname">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" required  data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-group="block2" />
    <span class="next btn btn-info pull-left" data-current-block="2" data-next-block="1">< Previous</span>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.next').on('click', function () {
    var current = $(this).data('currentBlock'),
      next = $(this).data('nextBlock');

    // only validate going forward. If current group is invalid, do not go further
    // .parsley().validate() returns validation result AND show errors
    if (next > current)
      if (false === $('#demo-form').parsley().validate('block' + current))
        return;

    // validation was ok. We can go on next step.
    $('.block' + current)
      .removeClass('show')
      .addClass('hidden');

    $('.block' + next)
      .removeClass('hidden')
      .addClass('show');

  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution or workaround is pretty simple. It's best just to use Bootstrap Wizard methods your going to want to have the following

```
$('#w4').bootstrapWizard({
        tabClass: 'wizard-steps',
        nextSelector: 'ul.pager li.next',
        previousSelector: 'ul.pager li.previous',
        firstSelector: null,
        lastSelector: null,
        onNext: function( tab, navigation, index, newindex ) {

            var current = index,
                next = current + 1;

            // only validate going forward. If current group is invalid, do not go further
            // .parsley().validate() returns validation result AND show errors
            if (next > current)
                if (false === $('#bioForm').parsley().validate('step' + current))
                    return false;

            // validation was ok. We can go on next step.
            $('.step' + current)
                .removeClass('show')
                .addClass('hidden');

            $('.step' + next)
                .removeClass('hidden')
                .addClass('show');

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but could help someone else in need .Had similar problem and this is how i solved it.

i added this to each control i need to validate on each steps 
add this to step1 controls :   data-parsley-group="block-1"
add this to step2 controls:   data-parsley-group="block-2"

....keep increasing for each steps.

in your bootstrapwizard javascript add the code below in the 'OnNext' fuction.

```
$('#form').bootstrapWizard({
        tabClass: 'wizard-steps',

       'onNext': function (tab, navigation, index) {
       var $valid = $("#form").parsley().validate({ group: 'block-' + index });
            if(!$valid) {
                return false;
            }
}
});
```

Hope this helps you out.